# Is there python way to match fragments within range

Tags: python, bioinformatics

I have a few genes that have been covered by different reads. One issue is that in certain cases where one gene is covered by multiple reads. I wish to catch all the fragments of reads that fit with gene length (range) [column 6 (genestart) and column 7 genestop] and add an end field stating the gene name along with alphabet "a" and for successive such finds I want the gene name with b added to it.

Input:

```
contig  230  3888 read1  1 8397 Gene1
contig  3343 3885 read2  1 8397 Gene1
contig  6030 8257 read4  1 8397 Gene1
contig  6030 8257 read10 1 8397 Gene1
contig  6260 8257 read7  1 8397 Gene1
contig  6030 8257 read8  1 8397 Gene1
contig  6190 6345 read10 1 8397 Gene1
contig   0   3124 read27 26 406 Gene12
contig  100  200  read30 26 406 Gene12
```

Desired output:

```
contig  230  3888 read1  1 8397 Gene1 Gene1a
contig  3343 3885 read2  1 8397 Gene1 covered
contig  6030 8257 read4  1 8397 Gene1 Gene1b
contig  6030 8257 read10 1 8397 Gene1 covered
contig  6260 8257 read7  1 8397 Gene1 covered
contig  6030 8257 read8  1 8397 Gene1 covered
contig  6190 6345 read10 1 8397 Gene1 covered
contig   0   3124 read27 26 406 Gene12 Gene12a
contig  100  200  read30 26 406 Gene12 covered
```

Code:

```
with open(input_file, "r") as f_in, open(output_file, "w") as f_out:
    gene_dict = {}
    for line in f_in:
        fields = line.strip().split()
        gene_name = fields[6]
        read_start = int(fields[1])
        read_end = int(fields[2])
        gene_start = int(fields[4])
        gene_end = int(fields[5])
        if gene_name not in gene_dict:
            gene_dict[gene_name] = []
        gene_found = False
        for gene_frag in gene_dict[gene_name]:
            frag_start = gene_frag[0]
            frag_end = gene_frag[1]
            if read_start <= frag_start <= read_end or read_start <= frag_end <= read_end:
                gene_found = True
                break
        if gene_found:
            gene_dict[gene_name].append((gene_start, gene_end))
            gene_count = chr(ord('a') + len(gene_dict[gene_name]) - 1)
            fields.append(f"{gene_name}{gene_count}")
        else:
            gene_dict[gene_name] = [(gene_start, gene_end)]
            fields.append(f"{gene_name}")
        f_out.write("\t".join(fields) + "\n")
```

I am not getting the desired output. The output I got

```
contig  230  3888 read1  1 8397 Gene1 Gene1
contig  3343 3885 read2  1 8397 Gene1 Gene1
contig  6030 8257 read4  1 8397 Gene1 Gene1
contig  6030 8257 read10 1 8397 Gene1 Gene1
contig  6260 8257 read7  1 8397 Gene1 Gene1
contig  6030 8257 read8  1 8397 Gene1 Gene1
contig  6190 6345 read10 1 8397 Gene1 Gene1
contig   0   3124 read27 26 406 Gene12 Gene12
contig  100  200  read30 26 406 Gene12 Gene12
```

The file is tab-delimited although here I haven't constructed the example tab.
Please provide pointers on where I am going wrong.

Comment: Those of us who are not bioinformatics have a hard time following your exposition. The problem does not seem hard to solve but perhaps you'd like to unpack the exposition a little bit more.

Comment: Also, incidentally, `chr(ord('a'))` is a really crazy way to write just `'a'` (-:

Comment: I wish to check if the value range in column 2 and column 3 falls within the range in columns 5 and 6. In my case multiple cases of range in column 2 and column 3 falls hence I want to add a gene naem+alphabet to indicate each match with the range. For successive matches within a gene I want to write the genename and increment the alphabet.

Comment: For `Gene1`, `read_start <= frag_start <= read_end or read_start <= frag_end <= read_end` will never be true. Please recheck the conditions. Also, `Gene1a` will never be output. Perhaps you need `fields.append(f"{gene_name}a")` for gene not found. And obviously your code does not contain any statement about `covered`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below code has the desired output. I've taken the input as a multiline string and output via prints for ease on my end, so some adapting required.

I've tried to comment the steps, but do ask if not clear. I've used `range()` and `set()` logic to find overlaps.

```
data='''contig  230  3888 read1  1 8397 Gene1
contig  3343 3885 read2  1 8397 Gene1
contig  6030 8257 read4  1 8397 Gene1
contig  6030 8257 read10 1 8397 Gene1
contig  6260 8257 read7  1 8397 Gene1
contig  6030 8257 read8  1 8397 Gene1
contig  6190 6345 read10 1 8397 Gene1
contig   0   3124 read27 26 406 Gene12
contig  100  200  read30 26 406 Gene12 '''

#initialise variables
last_gene=''
gene_span=range(0)
total_read_span=range(0)

for contig in data.split('\n'): #iterate over contigs
    fields=contig.split() #split lines into separate fields. Will need to be .split('\t) for tab-separated data
    read_span=range(int(fields[1]),int(fields[2])+1)
    if (gene := fields[6]) != last_gene: #check if new gene or previous gene
        last_gene=gene
        alphabet=iter('abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvqxyz') #set up an alphabet iterator to assign gene suffixes
        gene_span=range(int(fields[4]),int(fields[5])+1)
        total_read_span=range(0) #initialise total_read_span, i.e. the range of the sequence read
    if len(set(read_span)&set(gene_span)): #check if read or gene spans overlap (the length of a set of intersecting values > 0)
        if len(set(read_span)-set(total_read_span)): #check if the contig read has values outside of current total read span
            print(f'{contig} {gene}{next(alphabet)}')
            total_read_span=range(min(total_read_span.start,read_span.start),max(total_read_span.stop,read_span.stop)) #update total read span
        else:
            print(f'{contig} covered')
    else:
        print(f'{fields[3]} has no overlap with {gene}')
```

Comment: Thanks it worked out well!! The iteration of the alphabets was really good one.

Comment: nice one, as for the alphabet, python's `string` lib has `ascii_lowercase` which exactly this string :) https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#string.ascii_lowercase

Comment: It does, but implementing that is about as long as typing it out, and then I have to remember it too!